# Redirect www to non www with SSL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have seen many articles on rewrites, but I have a problem.

example.com => https:// example.com (OK)
www.example.com => https:// example.com (OK)
https:// example.com => https:// example.com (OK)
https:// www.example.com => https:// example.com (FAIL)

He tried several forum solutions, but I have the same problem. Now my htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

In your code, the second test is not performed with http, and %1 is not correct.